# WebSocket server clustering with state sharing in Kubernetes deployment

Tags: node.js, websocket, state-management

I am looking for a way to cluster WebSocket servers - written in node - so that a proper load balancing and a client request will be served by appropriate node instance. In case of WebSocket, the connection is stateful and I believe a node cluster could help. I want the connection/state information to be shared so that any node instance could serve the request than the client does not need to keep a track of the specific node instance. The reason for this thought process is to ensure that the node instances can be killed and replaced by new instances without bothering about the overheads of state management.

Answer (score 0):

I have a setup where we use multiple instances with load balancers in AWS ECS, deployed by CI/CD pipelines. The number of frontend and backend servers varies between 2 and 8 each depending on bursts and current deployments. If one server crashes, a new one will take its place.

We use [socket.io](https://socket.io/) with the [Redis adapter](https://socket.io/) to share the websocket state between all connected instances via the in-memory db [Redis](https://redis.io/). This ensures that even if the clients are connected to different instances, they all receive the events.